# Allow Vue2 Select Component to take in any array for select options

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, html-select

I'm trying to create a reusable Select component that will work with any Array passed to it as options.

I have it working if the Object properties in the array share the same names bound in the component, but if you pass an array of objects that have different property/attribute names, as expected, the options will not render. How can I assign on the component which object property I want as the option value and which I want as the option label/name?

**FormSelect.vue / Component**

```
<template>
   <select :id="id" v-model="selected">     
      <option v-if="options.length > 0" value="">Please Select</option>
      <option
        v-if="options.length > 0"
        v-for="(option, index) in options"
        :key="index"
        :selected="selected"
        :value="option.value"
        v-text="option.name"
       />  

    </select>
</template>
```

```
<script>
props: {
 value: {    
      type: [Array, String, Number, Object],
      default: null
    },
 options: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
},

computed: {
    selected: {
      get() {
        return this.value ? this.value : "";
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("input", v);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Parent.vue / Parent**

```html
<form-select
   id="gender"
   label="Gender"
   :options="genderOptions"
   @input="handleEdit(deep(profile))"
   v-model="user.gender"
/>
```

**This works:**

```
genderOptions: [
  { name: "Male", value: "MALE" },
  { name: "Female", value: "FEMALE" }
],
```

**This would not (notice obj key names):**

```
genderOptions: [
    { id: "Male", gender: "MALE" },
    { id: "Female", gender: "FEMALE" }
 ],
```

So I'm thinking there needs to be a way to tell the component which properties I want to use as the option value and label.  Something like this, but then it would also need to be handles on the component side:

```html
<form-select
   id="gender"
   label="Gender"
   :options="genderOptions"

   optionVal="gender"
   optionName="id"

   @input="handleEdit(deep(profile))"
   v-model="user.gender"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to add `optionVal` and `optionName` props to your component and to work with them, i suggest the following solution

```
<script>
props: {
 value: {    
      type: [Array, String, Number, Object],
      default: null
    },
 options: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    },
optionVal:{
    type:String,
    default: 'value'
    },
optionName:{
    type:String,
    default: 'name'
    }
},

computed: {
    selected: {
      get() {
        return this.value ? this.value : "";
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit("input", v);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```
 <select :id="id" v-model="selected">     
      <option v-if="options.length > 0" value="">Please Select</option>
      <option
        v-if="options.length > 0"
        v-for="(option, index) in options"
        :key="index"
        :selected="selected"
        :value="option[optionVal]"
    v-text="option[optionName]"
       />  

    </select>
```

Comment: Wow.. that works! ( :value="option[optionVal]" ).  Thank You!  I was definitely overthinking this one.  Can you explain how it still works without naming optionVal & optionName when the options DO have the right obj keys?

Comment: we have two ways to access object properties by . (dot) or by [] like `user.name` or `user["name"]`, so i used the second when since it's dynamical

Comment: Ahh, I see what you did with the prop defaults ('name' and 'value').. that's why it was still working without me setting a value for optionVal.  Great job and thanks again!